# How can manage CLR version of referenced assembly

Tags: .net

Project A has a reference to Project B. Project A runs on .NET 4.0 (CLR 4) and Project B run on .NET 3.5 (CLR 2). Is it true that while running Project A, Project B runs on CLR 4 (in other words, the referenced assembly runs the same CLR version as the calling assembly)?

I tried this on two projects and verified using the Environment. Version property on Project B, and that's how it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048277/can-i-have-my-assembly-reference-any-version-of-another-assembly try this link also http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep there's only one version of the clr loaded per process.