# Pass an object from one version of library to another one

Tags: c#, type-conversion, versioning

Suppose I have an application `A` and it uses library `B`. Both of them need another library `C` to work. `C` is strongly-named and versioned. Let's say that `B` was built to work with `C` version 1.0 and and `A` was built to work with `C` version 1.1

When `A` calls methods in `B` it passes some classes that are originated from `C` and this causes a problem as we have `C` with different versions. So I need to cast some class from `C 1.1` to `C 1.0`. How do such problems usually solved? `C` is developed backward-compatible so on paper that should be possible.

In my case `A` calls `B` via reflection, not sure whether this is important.

Comment: You need to add some more specifics, like some rudimentary code examples.  If you are conforming to a specific interface, versioning shouldn't matter.  If you  have two different interfaces, use the Adapter pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874975/is-it-possible-to-replace-a-reference-to-a-strongly-named-assembly-with-a-weak. Especially see the bit about assembly binding redirection.